# How can I prove, the sequence converges to the given limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that the sequence $ {f(n)}$ defined by $$0<f(1)<f(2) \\ f(n+2) = [f(n+1)\cdot f(n)]^{1/2}$$ for $n \geq 1$ converges to $$[f(1) \cdot  {f(2)}^2]^{1/3}$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Please read the detailed guidelines and rules [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) before asking questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: take the logarithm of $f(n)$ and turn it into a linear difference equation.

After that there's a shortcut to solve the equation, see
[Finding explicit formula for recursive relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903217/finding-explicit-formula-for-recursive-relation/3903918#3903918)