# Recursively defined sequences exercises.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

The sequence $ \{a_n \} $ defined recursively as,

$ a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2 $ and $ a_ {n + 2} = \dfrac{1}{2} (a_n + a_ {n + 1}) $ for $ n> 3 $.

I tried and found that the limit of that series is given by $ \dfrac {2} {3} \cdot 2+ \dfrac {1} {3} $ but I don't know if that result is good.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  How did you obtain it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [characteristic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) to solve it. $$2x^2-x-1=0 \implies x = 1 \text{ or } x = -\frac{1}{2}$$ Therefore $a_n = (1)^n \cdot c_0+(-\frac{1}{2})^n\cdot c_1 \implies 1 = a_1 = c_0-\frac{1}{2}c_1$ and $2 = a_2=c_0+\frac{1}{4}c_1 \implies c_0=\frac{5}{3}$ and $c_1=\frac{4}{3}$, which means that $$a_n=\frac{5}{3}+(-\frac{1}{2})^n\cdot\frac{4}{3} \implies \lim_{n \to\infty}(a_n)=\frac{5}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n+2}-a_{n+1} = -\frac 12 (a_{n+1}-a_n) \implies a_{n+1}-a_n=\left(-\frac 12\right)^{n-1} (a_2-a_1) = \left(-\frac 12\right)^{n-1}\tag 1
$$

$$a_{n+2}+\frac 12 a_{n+1} = a_{n+1} + \frac 12 a_n \implies a_{n+1} + \frac 1 2 a_n= a_2+\frac 12 a_1 = \frac 52 \tag 2
$$

(2) - (1)
$$
a_n = \frac 23 \left(\frac 52 - \left(-\frac 12 \right)^{n-1} \right)
$$

Check here for an explanation: [Finding explicit formula for recursive relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903217/finding-explicit-formula-for-recursive-relation/3903918#3903918)

Answer (score -1):

Using a standard method for

[solving homogeneous linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients),

it can be seen that $a_n=\dfrac53+\dfrac43\left(-\dfrac12\right)^n$, so you are correct that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\dfrac53$.