# How can I find a generating function of $a_n = 8a_{n-1} + 10^{n-1}, a_0=1$ with recurrence relation?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

With $a_0 =1$, $a_n = 8a_{n-1} + 10^{n-1}$

Let a generating function with it, $G(x) = \sum a_k x^k$ = $a_0 + \sum (8a_{k-1} +10^{k-1}) x^k =a_0 + \sum 8a_{k-1}x^k + \sum10^{k-1} x^k  = a_0 + 8x\sum a_kx^k + x\sum10^{k} x^k $

Now I think that, $\sum 10^k x^k \neq\frac{1}{1-10x}$, since it has no limitation on $x$, such as $|x|<1$ (If so, $10^nx^n$ cannot be less than 1, too).

What should I do? How can I deal with $\sum 10^k x^k$ ??

Or is it fine to do just like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating function uses formal power series.  As long as there is some radius of convergence, the result will apply.

We have
$$\begin{align}
G(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k \\
&= a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (8a_{k-1} + 10^{k-1})x^k \\
&= a_0 + 8x \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k + x \sum_{k=0}^\infty (10x)^k \\
&= 1 + 8x G(x) + \frac{x}{1 - 10x} \\
&= 8x G(x) + \frac{1 - 9x}{1 - 10x}.
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $$G(x) = \frac{1 - 9x}{(1 - 8x)(1 - 10x)} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{1-8x} + \frac{1}{1-10x}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (8^k + 10^k) x^k$$ and $$a_n = \frac{8^n + 10^n}{2}$$ and you can check that this works.

Comment: Well then, we have an assumption that $|10x| < 1$? I am confusing at that point...

Comment: Also, the form of $a_n$ is somewhat different from Marin's answer, [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3937669/how-to-solve-recurrence-relation-a-k-ba-k%e2%88%921-crk-assuming-b-neq-r],

Comment: At first, I did like what you did, but I think it is wrong, because of $10x$, so is it fine to do? It is just an assumption?

Comment: @JAEMTO You can assume that $|x|<\frac{1}{10}$, or $|x|<\frac{1}{100}$, or $|x|<\frac{1}{1000}$. I mean, why couldn't you?

Comment: @Gary Yes in that case, I understand it, but I am wondering that if I can think of for any $x$, like $x=2$... is it just an assumption for recurrence relation for what you said?

Comment: @JAEMTO No, you can't. But from the viewpoint of the problem it does not matter. What matters is that the series converge in *some* neighbourhood of the origin. The size of it is totally irrelevant. I feel that you have not embraced the concept of a generating function fully yet.

Comment: @Gary Yeah I have studied generating function these days... Then what you mean is that $x$ should be in some neighborhood for convergence? That is an assumption because if $x$ is not in some neighborhood for convergence, then it just diverges and it has no meaning, is that right?

Comment: @Gary Oh... generating function is important, because we can get $a_n $ easily, if there is a convergence radius, without too much calculation, is that right?

Comment: @JAEMTO Yes, you can obtain a closed form of the sequence using a generating function if you are lucky. The convergence is nedeed so that you can write down a closed form for the function represented by the power series.